# How to change random values copying from Excel to Date in R

Tags: r, dataframe

The data was in Date format but when I read the xlsx file in R, it changes to some weird value.

```
| ID |Date|
|----|----|
| 01 |44589|
| 02 |44590| 
| 03 |44689|
```

So I tried:

```
as.Date(parse_date_time(new_df$date, orders = c('ymd')))
as.Date(parse_date_time(new_df$date, orders = c('ymd')))
```

But it doesn't help at all. Where did I go wrong?
I also tried

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(data$`Date (DD/MM/YY)`, origin = "1900-01-01"))
```

It only outputs NA

Comment: See the 'Examples' section of `?as.Date` - these probably represent the number of days since the Excel origin date, which might be `"1899-12-30"` or `"1904-01-01"` depending on what system or version made this file.

Comment: @thelatemail  the excel version is 2108

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything fancy like `` data$`Date (DD/MM/YY)' ``  on that second attempt because the magritter `%>%` is sending the dataframe in anyway. Try this:

```
data <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3),
                   Date = c(44589, 44590, 44689))


data <- data %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(Date, origin = "1899-12-30"))
```